# List1 = List2 = [] as opposed to List1 = [], List2 = []

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I was fiddling about with some code for a linear regression lecture i'm giving, and was wondering (for quite some time actually), why my code was producing far too many outputs.

I load a csv file with 7 rows into a DataFrame, and create al ist of all possible combinations of indicies, with the following:

```
perms = combinations(df.index.tolist(), 2)
```

And then because i'm not that skilled in python yet, i still use "append" to calculate slopes and intercepts of various combinations of the points in the DataFrame through the following code:

```
slopes = []
intercepts = []

for permutation in perms:
         slopes.append(calculate_slope(df.loc[permutation[0], ["revenue", "apples sold"]], df.loc[permutation[1], ["revenue", "apples sold"]]))
         intercepts.append(calculate_intercept(df.loc[permutation[0]], slopes[-1]))
```

However, when i used `slopes = intercepts = []` it created an output of twice the length? The length is quite important as in this example AB = BA, so i don't want to include the extra sets.

In essence, my question is what is the difference between `slopes = intercepts = []` and

```
slopes = []
intercepts = []
```

Thanks in advance! If you're able to do the list-comprehension in a more intelligent way, please let me know :-)

Comment: `slopes = intercepts = []` one object with 2 references.   `slopes = []
intercepts = []` two objects with one reference each.

Comment: Simply, in first case you're assigning an empty list to `intercepts` and then `intercepts` to `slopes`. This means that you're creating two references to one object. But in second case you're creating two separate objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat rlunde.py 
slopes = intercepts = []

print id(slopes)
print id(intercepts)

slopes = []
intercepts = []

print id(slopes)
print id(intercepts)

$ python rlunde.py 
140181275420648
140181275420648
140181275421728
140181275454280
```

when you write slopes = intercepts = [], slopes and intercepts refers to the same list (same id)

whereas when you write: slopes = []; intercepts = [], you have 2 lists.